# Mapping Webform picklist values to different values on Picklist in Salesforce

Tags: picklist

I'm not a developer by any means, but better want to understand what is feasible out of the box with Salesforce.  Scenario is I'm thinking of a web form that will act as a landing page for customer inquiry so the language on it will be different than what we would want used on the backend for some options but not all.

For example:

| Webform Value | Backend Value |
| --- | --- |
| Inquiry about Existing Order | Order Inquiry |
| Inquiry about Payment issue | Payment Inquiry |
| Shipping | Shipping |

Is something like this doable out of the box with Salesforce? I'm looking but don't see any easy way of doing it personally but my googlefu may be failing me.  Or is it possible to set up some sort of mapping table for only select values that I cannot find?

Comment: Salesforce does not have a general-purpose web form tool. What feature or product are you expecting to use to manage your form?

Comment: It is my understanding the developers would in theory build the webform using LWC.

Comment: If you build a code-based solution with LWC, you can write code to do whatever data transformations you need

Comment: Okay, I think that makes sense. No easy in between which i was hoping for.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picklists can be translated in the [Translation Workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.workbench.htm&type=5). These translations are available in LWC, Aura, Visualforce, Apex, and API, for both Communities and the UI. If you're using a separate tool, Salesforce supports "API Values" for picklist values, which mean you can show any value/translation you want, yet still maintain a consistent value in the database. As such, the general answer is "yes, Salesforce can do this".